# Feature `declaration expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification

Tags: c#, linux, vps

I am trying to build an SLN File on an Ubuntu Linux VPS. However, I am getting a bunch of errors.

```
        networking/handlers/CreateGuildHandler.cs(42,77): error CS1644: Feature `declaration expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification
        networking/Client.cs(45,16): error CS1043: Invalid accessor body `=>', expecting `;' or `{'
        networking/Client.cs(46,25): error CS1043: Invalid accessor body `=>', expecting `;' or `{'
        networking/Client.cs(124,41): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `when'
        networking/Client.cs(124,43): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `<operator>'
        networking/Client.cs(142,74): error CS1644: Feature `declaration expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification
        networking/handlers/UsePortalHandler.cs(32,43): error CS1644: Feature `type pattern matching' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification
        networking/handlers/PlayerShootHandler.cs(23,96): error CS1644: Feature `declaration expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification
        networking/handlers/CreateHandler.cs(27,107): error CS1644: Feature `declaration expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification
        realm/entities/vendors/MerchantLists.cs(114,99): error CS1644: Feature `declaration expression' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification
```

Please may I get some help? I have looked around and none of the answers worked.

Comment: Well, how are you compiling it? What version of the compiler are you using? What language version did you specify in your project file?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the compiler knows what it means, but isn't letting you use them, means that you *have* a suitable compiler, but: the project itself is set to use a lower-level language version. Check the project file to see if it is specified explicitly, or: add a new `<LangVersion>` element if it is missing, with a higher language version.